# Why coerce not triggered when i use ""*Point

Tags: ruby

I am trying to figure out the `coerce` method. when I defined the `*` method and `coerce` method. `integer * Point` triggers `coerce`, but `"" * Point` doesn't trigger. Why?

The error is:

```
coerce.rb:34:in `*': no implicit conversion of Point into Integer (TypeError)   from coerce.rb:34:in `<main>'
```

The code is:

```
class Point
  def initialize x,y
    @x,@y = x,y
  end

  def * x
    p "* called" 
    @x *= x
    @y *= x
  end

  def coerce other
    p 'coerce called'

    if other.is_a? String
      p "converted"
      [self, other.to_i]
    else
      [self,other]
    end
    #[3,other]
  end
end

p1= Point.new 1,1
p1*2
p p1
2*p1
p p1

p p1.coerce(2)

p "string test====="
"2" * p1
```

The output:

```
"* called"
#<Point:0x00564f5de89dd0 @x=2, @y=2>
"coerce called"
"* called"
#<Point:0x00564f5de89dd0 @x=4, @y=4>
"coerce called"
[#<Point:0x00564f5de89dd0 @x=4, @y=4>, 2]
"string test====="
coerce.rb:34:in `*': no implicit conversion of Point into Integer (TypeError)
    from coerce.rb:34:in `<main>'
```

Who can tell me why and how to make `"2" * p1` work?

Comment: The method [String#*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-2A) in `"2" * p1` requires an integer for it's argument, but `p1` is an instance of `Point`. Ruby is unable to coerce `p1` into an integer.

Comment: What do you expect `"2" * p1` to return?

Comment: @spickermann  I want it works like   2 * p1

Comment: @CarySwoveland Why ruby not call coerce just like 2 * p1. how can i make it work like that? thanks

Comment: You haven't answered @spickermann's question. `p1` is an instance you have defined. In doing so you set the values of two instance variables equal to `1`. Do you want `"2" * p1` to return `'cat'` or `324` or `['2', '2']`? No? Then what should it return?

Comment: @CarySwoveland,  I want: "2" * p1 #return <Point: @x=2,@y=2> if p1 is <Point: @x=1,@y=1)
and I wonder why the coerce is not tirggered like 2*p1. and how to make it triggered?

Comment: @Martin You **could** re-define the `*` method on `String`, but that's not a good idea. What is `"x" * "y"`? You get the same error as above, because it doesn't make any sense. `string * something` is expected to return another String; it would be very weird if that method suddenly behaved like `Point * Integer`.

Comment: @TomLord, thanks. yes, I know it's weird.  I am trying to figure out why the coerce function is not triggered if I use (String)*(Point) instead of (Integer)*(Point)? The reason is that the String has a function of (String)*(Integer)?

Comment: @Martin type coercion is not a general built-in language feature. `coerce` works for numeric operation only because those operator methods call `coerce` explicitly. `String` does not.

Comment: @Stefan, Thank you very much! I understand it now. I took coercion as a general feature. Thanks!

Comment: Here's an example of numeric coercion. The instance method [String#*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-2A) expects an argument that is a non-negative integer, such as `"2" * 3 #=> "222"`. However, Ruby will allow the argument to be other types of numeric values, which it will convert to an integer. Here are some examples: `"2" * 3.0 #=> "222"; "2" * 3.5 #=> "222"; "2" * Rational(10,3) #=> "222"; require 'bigdecimal'; "s" * BigDecimal(3) #=> "sss"`. This does not apply to all numeric types, however:  `"2" * Complex(3,5) #=> RangeError (can't convert 3+5i into Integer)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, thanks. I had taken the coercion as a general feature before Stefan explained that to me. I was trying to make it a general feature.

Answer (score 2):

The catch here is that while Ruby allows you to redefine operators for this, these are very particular about the ordering.

Remember that this code:

```
point * 2
```

Ends up being understood by Ruby as:

```
point.send(:*, 2)
```

Which is the method you have defined that handles this particular case, `Point#*`.

While this code:

```
2 * point
```

Ends up being understood as:

```
2.send(:*, point)
```

Where that goes off to `Integer#*` and you have no control over that. While you can patch it, that seems like an *extraordinarily* bad idea. The best thing is to document how your system works and show examples of the correct ordering.

In Ruby the left-hand value in a binary operator basically calls the shots, the right-hand value is just a passenger.

Comment: Though not your main point (I was glad to see you use `send` in your explanation), if Martin wants `p1 * "2"` to return the same value as `p2 * 2` one could write `def * x;  p "* called"; n = x.to_i; @x *= n; @y *= n; end`, since `'2'.to_i #=> 2` and `2.to_i #=> 2`.

Comment: thanks, @tadman.Just as Cary Swoveland said. I was trying to make coercion a general feature. And I Did try to patch the String class to trigger the coerce of the Point. but I did it ugly. Does anyone have an elegant way (to Patch the String class)?

Comment: That's something you're really not supposed to do, so it's ugly on purpose. A feature, not a bug, of the Ruby language. You *can* do it, but they won't make it easy.